# Getting Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object' when running React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules, create-react-app

I created a React App using `npx create-react-app my_app` but when I am running the app using `npm start`, I am getting the following error,

[image]

I tried installing the package '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object' using `npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object` but still getting the same error. How to solve this?

Comment: Says [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-private-property-in-object) that this plugin is already included in `babel/preset-env`. Are you sure you need to be installing it separately at all? Might be a bug with `create-react-app` if you're actually doing a fresh bootstrap

Comment: No we do not need to install the package separately, Idk why it's showing an error this time.

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a combination of **babel packages** that worked for me:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.22.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "7.21.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.22.5",
}
```

**IMPORTANT STEP**

Add `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object` to **.babelrc plugins** as well.

Something like this:

```json
"plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }]
]
```

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs when Babel plugin is missing or not installed.
Add "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.0", to the list of dependencies in the package.json file like:

"dependencies": {

```
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

After receiving a warning "One of your dependencies, babel-preset-react-app, is importing the package "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" without declaring it in its dependencies. This is currently working because the package "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is already in your node_modules folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any time." I reinstalled @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object from the website https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that when you save this code in `package.json`, an additional error will show up. However, if you remove it and save it again, both issues are resolved and the code compiles perfectly.

```js
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object": "^7.23.3"
  }
```

**(If someone knows a permanent solution, please do reply to this)**

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Add a babel.config.js file to the root of the project

**Step2:** 2: Run this code in the terminal

```
npm i @babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object
```

**Step 3:** Add the code below to the Babel.config file

```
plugins: [
    ...
    require('@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object').default,
    require('@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods').default
];
```

**Step 4:** Add these lines of code to the package.json file

```
  "devDependencies": {
  "@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object": "^7.23.3"
 },
```

Answer (score -1):

Followed all the above resolutions but still receive this error when examining 'http://localhost:3000/' in a browser:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/MinimizableWebChat.js 11:0-67

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'botframework-webchat' in '/Users/miteshparmar/Documents/WebSite_creation/BotFramework-WebChat-main/samples/06.recomposing-ui/a.minimizable-web-chat/src'


ERROR in ./src/WebChat.js 7:0-86

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'botframework-webchat' in '/Users/miteshparmar/Documents/WebSite_creation/BotFramework-WebChat-main/samples/06.recomposing-ui/a.minimizable-web-chat/src'
```

Also my Mac Terminal shows the following:

```
Failed to compile.
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'botframework-webchat' in '/Users/miteshparmar/Documents/WebSite_creation/BotFramework-WebChat-main/samples/06.recomposing-ui/a.minimizable-web-chat/src'
ERROR in ./src/MinimizableWebChat.js 11:0-67
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'botframework-webchat' in '/Users/miteshparmar/Documents/WebSite_creation/BotFramework-WebChat-main/samples/06.recomposing-ui/a.minimizable-web-chat/src'

ERROR in ./src/WebChat.js 7:0-86
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'botframework-webchat' in '/Users/miteshparmar/Documents/WebSite_creation/BotFramework-WebChat-main/samples/06.recomposing-ui/a.minimizable-web-chat/src'

webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35793404)